# "this.extButton is null" error when manually defining aloha's toolbar settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, aloha-editor

I am using aloha in a web application. It works very well and does everything I need to do. The only problem is, as soon as I try to add the following settings to customize the toolbar,

```
Aloha.settings = {
    ...
    toolbar: {
        tabs: {
            Format: []
            Insert: []
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

I get start getting this error in the browser console:

```
this.extButton is null
```

if I remove the toolbar section from the settings and use the default settings for toolbar, everything works fine. also, please note that at this point I have not customize the code at all, so no custom plugin or other code has been added.

has anyone else encountered this issue? any way to get around it?

Comment: I am having the same problem, anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are overwritting all the settings. `extButton` was probably a setting that you didn't include when you overwrote `Aloha.settings`.

Try this:

```
Aloha.settings = $.extend(true, Aloha.settings, {
    // Your settings here
});
```